# How to get _id of Models in Mongoose (Typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm using Mongoose to model mongodb object (node.js / nestJS)

#### Goal

I want to have the `_id` - which is automatically created by MongoDB - of an object in a POJO exposed. Because I need them on client side for some operations. (identify same objects, ...)

#### What I tried

```
export type GroupDocument = Group & Document;

@Schema()
export class Group {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    name: string;
}
```

Given the code above, I can access the `_id` when I use

```
const group: GroupDocument = this.findOne();
```

which is fine. In most of the cases I don't want to work with the whole `GroupDocument` object, because it has a lot of overhead and it's recommended to work with `LeanDocuments` as much as possible. But when I call `.lean()` on a GroupDocument, the `_id` gets lost and I can't access it anymore.

```
const group: = this.findOne().lean();
```

It works if I would extend my Group from Documents like so:

```
Group extends Document
```

But this isn't recommended by mongoose

I also thought about just putting the _id into the POJO like so:

```
@Schema()
export class Group {

    _id: string;

    @Prop({ required: true })
    name: string;
}
```

But this seems to me not an ideal solution.

All I want to do is to make it possible to call `group.id` / `group._id` on a lean object. Is there any way to achieve that without harming any best practices?

Comment: i think you can get id of object on creation of its model also

Answer (score 2):

You have to define _id as:

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';
_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

To return just the '_id' field you could use [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in database and just return the _id field

Answer (score 0):

Just Define `id as a string`. Mongoose will convert the ObjectId to a string and sets it to the id field.

Example:

```
@Schema() 
export class Group {
  id: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;
}
```

Note: Don't annotate the id field with @Prop

Answer (score 0):

You can define your model as

```
export type UserModel = Model<Require_id<User>>;
```

then the `_id` should still be available